# Is there a way I can detect if there is any of a list inside of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable called 'command' and I want to check whether command contains any of a certain list. For instance, if I have a list with ["a", "b", "c"] and I want to detect if command has any of those elements in it. So if command is "abc" it will return true for that if statement and if command is "ABC" it will return false.

Comment: Be careful that you don't run into the [Scunthorp problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Answer (score 3):

```py
def command_contains_element(command, element_list):
    return any(c in command for c in element_list)
```

Comment: I don't understand the syntax for any(). What is the "for" and "in" for?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `element_list` instead of `candidate_list` in the second line?

Answer (score -1):

This might do the work:

```
isTrue = False
for i in ["a","b","c"]: #List you said
    if i in command: #command "abc"
        isTrue = True
        break
print(isTrue)
```

Comment: This is going to print True or False 3 times, definitely not what the problem asked for.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks for pointing it out @MarkRansom